# Quickstart sample code - NuGet dependencies are broken

Tags: identityserver4

I am new to IndentityServer and am trying to following the document to setup the Quickstart VS.Net solution on my Windows 10 desktop. After following instructions downloading and installing source code and opening up the solution in VS.Net 2017, I noticed that both NuGet dependencies - IdentityServer4 (4.0.0) and Serilog.AspNetCore (3.2.0) - are broken. Compiling the solution returns with an error: "NETSDK1045   The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.". I also tried installing NuGet packages for those 2 components but it made no difference.

Could someone show me what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer4 v4.00 requires.NET Core 3.1, and because of that you need to use the latest Visual Studio 2019 and install the latest 3.1 SDKs.

Comment: Thanks Tore. I will get my VS2019 then.

Comment: Sorry Tore. I have been looking for a button or link that says something like "mark as answer" or "accept the answer" but I still don't see it. That's why I just replied. I apologize for that. As I said I am entirely new to this platform.

Comment: Finally found it! Thanks again for your help Tore!